# Plupload in magento

Tags: module, file-upload

I am using plupload in custom module in magento

This is my phtml:

```
<?php 
//session_start();
$param = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'); 
$_SESSION['id'] = $param;
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/plupload.full.min.js')?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
var jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){              
        jQuery("#button2").click(function(){               

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<?php echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('management/adminhtml_task/show')?>',
                data:   jQuery('#commentForm').serialize()  ,
                success: function(response){
                    //alert(response);
                  jQuery('#div1').after(response);
                  document.getElementById('comments1').value='';
                 // document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML='';
                }
            });  return false;

        });
    });

</script>

<form method="POST" action="#" name="commentForm" id="commentForm">

<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()?>" />
<table>
<tr>
<td>Comments:</td>

<td><textarea name="comments1" id="comments1" rows="2" cols="70"></textarea></td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" id="button2">Submit</button></td>
</tr>
<!--<tr>
<td>File Upload:</td>
<td><input type="file" name="files" id="files" ></td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="submit" id="button23">Submit1</button></td>

</tr>-->


</table>
<div name="filelist" id="filelist">Your browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight or HTML5 support.</div>


<div id="container">
    <a id="pickfiles" href="javascript:;">[Select files]</a> 
    <a id="uploadfiles" href="javascript:;">[Upload files]</a>
</div>


<pre id="console"></pre>

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
    browse_button : 'pickfiles', // you can pass in id...
    container: document.getElementById('container'), // ... or DOM Element itself
    url : '<?php echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('management/adminhtml_task/view')?>',


    filters : {
        max_file_size : '10mb',
        mime_types: [
            {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
            {title : "Zip files", extensions : "zip"}
        ]
    },
    init: {
        PostInit: function() {
            document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML = '';
            document.getElementById('uploadfiles').onclick = function() {
                uploader.start();
                return false;
            };
        },
        FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
            plupload.each(files, function(file) {

                document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML += '<div id="' + file.id + '">' + file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ') <b></b></div><br/>';

            });
        },
        UploadProgress: function(up, file) {
            document.getElementById(file.id).getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML = '<span>' + file.percent + "%</span>";

        },
        Error: function(up, err) {
            document.getElementById('console').appendChild(document.createTextNode("Error #" + err.code + ": " + err.message +"\n"));
        }
    }
});
uploader.init();

</script>
```

How to upload file and make directory?
What code is use in viewAction?

Answer (score -1):

in viewAction:

```
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    $targetDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'plupload' ;
    $cleanupTargetDir = true; // Remove old files
    $maxFileAge = 5 * 3600; // Temp file age in seconds
    if (!file_exists($targetDir)) {
        @mkdir($targetDir);
    }       
    if (isset($_REQUEST["name"])) {
    $fileName = $_REQUEST["name"];
    } elseif (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    } else {
    $fileName = uniqid("file_");
    }

    $filePath = $targetDir . DS . $fileName;
    // Chunking might be enabled
    $chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunk"]) : 0;
    $chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunks"]) : 0;
    // Remove old temp files    
    if ($cleanupTargetDir) {
    if (!is_dir($targetDir) || !$dir = opendir($targetDir)) {
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 100, "message": "Failed to open temp directory."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }
    while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
    $tmpfilePath = $targetDir . DS . $file;
    // If temp file is current file proceed to the next
    if ($tmpfilePath == "{$filePath}.part") {
    continue;
    }
    // Remove temp file if it is older than the max age and is not the current file
    if (preg_match('/\.part$/', $file) && (filemtime($tmpfilePath) < time() - $maxFileAge)) {
    @unlink($tmpfilePath);
    }
    }
    closedir($dir);
    }   
    // Open temp file
    if (!$out = @fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunks ? "ab" : "wb")) {
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])) {
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 103, "message": "Failed to move uploaded file."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }
    // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
    if (!$in = @fopen($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "rb")) {
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }
    } else {    
    if (!$in = @fopen("php://input", "rb")) {
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }
    }
    while ($buff = fread($in, 4096)) {
    fwrite($out, $buff);
    }
    @fclose($out);
    @fclose($in);
    // Check if file has been uploaded
    if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {
    // Strip the temp .part suffix off 
    rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);
    }
    // Return Success JSON-RPC response
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : null, "id" : "id"}');
```

N one more correction in phtml file in plupload code between **url** & **filters:** write this code

```
  multipart_params: {
  form_key:'<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>'
  },
```